# How to fix badly configured SWD pin?

Tags: embedded, stm32, gpio, firmware

I accidentally flashed a program that configured the SWD pin as a GPIO so now I'm not able to flash my board. All my pins on my board are broken out so I can access them all. How do I reset my pin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just keep reset low when debugger connects to the micro. Manually or set the option "connect under reset"